# ls shows a timestamp with no time for a file on NFS

Tags: ls, nfs, timestamps

When we create a file on Linux we notice that the timestamp is not visible and the `stat` on the file shows a time in future, the filesystem is an NFS mount, has anyone seen this before?

```
aa:/usr/data> touch test
aa:/usr/data> ls -al test
-rw-r----- 1 iaaadm sapsys 0 Jun 30  2014 test
aa:/usr/data>  stat test
File: `test'
Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 32768  regular empty file
Device: 14h/20d Inode: 114999298   Links: 1
Access: (0640/-rw-r-----)  Uid: ( 1002/  aaadm)   Gid: (   86/  sys)
Access: 2014-06-30 18:35:44.000000000 -0500
Modify: 2014-06-30 18:35:44.000000000 -0500
Change: 2014-06-30 18:35:44.000000000 -0500
Birth: -
```

Comment: We can't tell from your post how large the time difference is. My guess for "a few minutes" is: NFS server and client have clocks that are slightly out of skew. "Almost exactly some hours" would point to some time zone misconfiguration.

Comment: thx, is the Linux Kernel configured not to show a timestamp if the time is in future .

Answer (score 1):

A timestamp in the future is a common consequence of using NFS when the client and the server have different times. To avoid this, make sure that your NFS client and your NFS server are synchronized to the same time source over [NTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol). In a small network, it's fairly common to have a central server that serves NFS, NTP and often other things. That server may be itself an NTP client getting the time from a reference clock, but that's less important than having a consistent time across your internal network.

As a user, coping with unsynchronized clocks between the NFS client and the server is a pain. If you aren't administrator, try to get the server administrator to run an NTP server (it's as easy as installing `ntpd` and setting the list of authorized clients in the configuration file) and the client administrator to run `ntpd` and set the source to the NFS/NTP server.

`ls` shows a timestamp with hours and minutes when the time is between six months ago and now, and with a year when the time is more than six months ago or in the future.

Comment: thx much Gilles, so there is no way an ls would show hours and minutes when the time is more than six months ago or in the future

Comment: @user74073 With GNU ls (i.e. on Linux or Cygwin), you can use `ls --full-time` to always show the year, and the time with nanosecond resolution.

Comment: thx much Gilles